# How to select the specific sibling of an ancestor using XPath

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<p>
  <!-- Span can be any level deep -->
  <span>
    Some text
  </span>
</p>

<!-- Any number of different elements between span and table -->
<p></p>
<div></div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using Nokogiri and custom XPath functions I am able to select the `<span>` element containing context that matches the regex. I am forced to do it this way since Nokogiri is using XPath 1.0 and there is no support for the `matches` selector:

```
@doc.xpath("//span[regex_match(text(), '/some text/i')]")
```

Having the `span` node selected, how do I select the table that is visually following the `span`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `contains` function to match the text. Then use `following::table` to find the table following this `span` tag.

```
@doc.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Some text')]/following::table")
```

Comment: I mainly added my answer because there was no need to use `parent::p`, the `following` axis would work directly from the `span`. Since you’ve fixed that here my answer is redundant so I’ve deleted it (you were first after all).